# Encountering error 2013 during SP call on large table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, indexing

I'm encountering a lost connection error during an SP call splits out dates from between a 'valid from' & 'valid to' column in Table A, and inserts them, along with additional columns, into a new table B.

Table A has about 3 million rows, so I expect that Table B will have possibly in excess of 10 million rows.

The SP runs for 600 seconds, and then displays the 2013 error.

I have tried calling this SP more than a few times, but without success.

How can I resolve this? 
Will partitioning Table A help in any way?

What about indexing?

Table A as below:

```
     CREATE TABLE `test_data`.`offer_master` (
      `off_id` INT NOT NULL primary key,
      `hot_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `curr_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `price_dollar` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `price_local` FLOAT NOT NULL,
      `curr_code` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
      `valid_from` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `valid_to` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `breakfast_included` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
      `valid_offer` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL)
       ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table B:

```
     CREATE TABLE `test_data`.`split_by_date` (
    `id` int NOT NULL, 
    `hotel_id` int not NULL,
    `original_price` float not NULL,
    `currency_id` int not NULL,
    `dates` date DEFAULT NULL)
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

SP that splits out the dates from A & inserts into B:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE `split_dates`()
BEGIN
DECLARE aid INT;
DECLARE avalid_from_date DATE;
DECLARE avalid_to_date DATE;
DECLARE sp_hotel_id INT;
DECLARE local_price float;
DECLARE sp_currency_id int;
DECLARE tempdt DATE;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE getdates CURSOR FOR 
SELECT off_id,valid_from,valid_to,hot_id,price_local,curr_id 
from offer_master;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN getdates;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH getdates 
INTO aid,avalid_from_date,avalid_to_date,sp_hotel_id,local_price,sp_currency_id;

    IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;  
END IF;

set tempdt=date(avalid_from_date);

WHILE (tempdt <= date(avalid_to_date)) do
  insert into split_by_date(id,hotel_id,original_price,currency_id,dates) 
  values(aid,sp_hotel_id,local_price,sp_currency_id,tempdt);
  set tempdt=tempdt+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
end while;


 END LOOP;
 CLOSE getdates;
 END
 //
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix might be

```
START TRANSACTION;
CALL ... ;
COMMIT;
```

The better fix is to realize that `CURSORs` are almost always the wrong way to write SQL.  We can get rid of the cursor by acting on all 3 million rows at once.  But I don't see how to get away from the `WHILE` loop.

```
SELECT @n := 0;  -- Or "1"?  (depends on whether you want to start with `valid_from`.
myloop:  LOOP
    INSERT INTO split_by_date(id, hotel_id, original_price, currency_id, dates)
        SELECT            off_id, hot_id,   price_local,    curr_id,
                          valid_from + INTERVAL n DAY
            FROM offer_master
            WHERE valid_from + INTERVAL @n DAY < valid_to;  -- maybe "<=" ?
    IF ROW_COUNT = 0 THEN
        LEAVE myloop;    -- when a pass over the data has no rows to add
    END IF
END LOOP myloop;
```

No `INDEX` or `PARTITION` will help; it simply needs to repeatedly do a table scan.

However, you really should have at least a `PRIMARY KEY` on every table.

It is not wise to use `FLOAT` for money.  See `DECIMAL`.